# Play multiple audio files using text links

Tags: javascript, html, audio

A similar question was answered on here about a single audio file with a text link. I need to know how to play a list of audio files on the same web page, each one using only a "listen" text link as the play button that changes to a "pause" link when playing. Here's the code I'm using to get one file to work. The problem is, when I simply copy/paste the same code using different id tags for the other audio, it doesn't work. It plays one file no matter which link I press. My code looks like this:

```
<audio id="clip1" preload='auto'>
<source src='audio/clip1.mp3' type='audio/mp3' />
</audio>

<audio id="clip2" preload='auto'>
<source src='audio/door.mp3' type='audio/mp3' />
</audio>

<a href="javascript:null()" id="door-control">Listen</a>
<a href="javascript:null()" id="bridge-control">Listen</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
var yourAudio = document.getElementById('bridge'),
ctrl = document.getElementById('bridge-control');

ctrl.onclick = function () {

// Update the Button
var pause = ctrl.innerHTML === 'Pause';
ctrl.innerHTML = pause ? 'Listen' : 'Pause';

// Update the Audio
var method = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';
yourAudio[method]();

// Prevent Default Action
return false;
};
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var yourAudio = document.getElementById('door'),
ctrl = document.getElementById('door-control');

ctrl.onclick = function () {

// Update the Button
var pause = ctrl.innerHTML === 'Pause';
ctrl.innerHTML = pause ? 'Listen' : 'Pause';

// Update the Audio
var method = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';
yourAudio[method]();

// Prevent Default Action
return false;
};
</script>
```

So one link plays the file just fine, but the other doesn't. It plays the first one as if it was the first link. Any solutions for how I can get them to play only their corresponding audio file, and pause anything else playing when they start? Thanks!

Comment: because in both scripts you are using the name `ctrl` for both the the links, when you make the anonymous functions they use `ctrl`, so each function is going to use what ctrl was set to last

Comment: It is because you define global variables `yourAudio` and `ctrl` twice.

Comment: See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CTZMp/) for correction

Answer (score 0):

Try wrap your scripts into function (you change variables scope to local inside the function), do something like this:

```
(function() {
    // your code here
})();
```

For your example it is

```
<audio id="clip1" preload='auto'>
<source src='audio/clip1.mp3' type='audio/mp3' />
</audio>

<audio id="clip2" preload='auto'>
<source src='audio/door.mp3' type='audio/mp3' />
</audio>

<a href="javascript:null()" id="door-control">Listen</a>
<a href="javascript:null()" id="bridge-control">Listen</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    var yourAudio = document.getElementById('bridge'),
        ctrl = document.getElementById('bridge-control');

    ctrl.onclick = function () {

        // Update the Button
        var pause = ctrl.innerHTML === 'Pause';
        ctrl.innerHTML = pause ? 'Listen' : 'Pause';

        // Update the Audio
        var method = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';
        yourAudio[method]();

        // Prevent Default Action
        return false;
    };
})();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
    var yourAudio = document.getElementById('door'),
        ctrl = document.getElementById('door-control');

    ctrl.onclick = function () {

        // Update the Button
        var pause = ctrl.innerHTML === 'Pause';
        ctrl.innerHTML = pause ? 'Listen' : 'Pause';

        // Update the Audio
        var method = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';
        yourAudio[method]();

        // Prevent Default Action
        return false;
    };
})();
</script>
```

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/zQeaL/). You have to change ids too.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, the problem is that you're defining the same variables multiple times in the global scope. This can get messy as you add more audio objects since you'll risk more name collisions. Assuming you're using the same handler for your control objects, I recommend re-factoring your code like so:

```
// List of audio/control pairs
var playlist = [{
    "audio": document.getElementById('bridge'),
    "control": document.getElementById('bridge-control')
}, {
    "audio": document.getElementById('door'),
    "control": document.getElementById('door-control')
}];

for (var i = 0; i < playlist.length; i++) {
    var obj = playlist[i];
    var audio = obj.audio;
    var control = obj.control;
    // returns a closure
    var listener = function (control, audio) {
        return function () {
            var pause = control.innerHTML === 'Pause';
            control.innerHTML = pause ? 'Listen' : 'Pause';
            // Update the Audio
            var method = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';
            audio[method]();
            // Prevent Default Action
            return false;
        }
    };
    control.addEventListener("click", listener(control, audio));
}
```

You can easily add more audio objects, and there's no need to duplicate your handler definition.

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CTZMp/1/)</kbd>